# How to add a database name to an AWS mysql RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

For a group project I have a database on AWS. In order to use the tables I need the name of the database, but the person who set the database up never set a name.

[image: The database name in the AWS Console]

Using this as the database url doesn't work:

```
instancename.someawsurl.amazonaws.com/
```

So I need it to look like this

```
instancename.someawsurl.amazonaws.com/thedatabasename
```

How can I add a database name here? I can't seem to find any options to add one.

Comment: Is this on RDS?

Comment: @JNevill yes it is.

Comment: Connect to the RDS, issue a `CREATE DATABASE foo` call, and use that new database. Not specifying a database name when creating the RDS just means it doesn't do that step for you.